# How to center a vertical navigation

Tags: html, css, center

This is the look I want to achieve http://tinyurl.com/qjsqmnp

I only want to use css and html. I've done a lot of research and tried one hell of a lot of things, but nothing seems to work :( it's just stuck on that upper left corner.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1r6esr7/
CSS:

```
ul {
text-align: left;
font-size: 16px;
height: 20%;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
height: 20%;
text-align: left;
}

ul a {
text-align: left;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
}

ul a:hover {
color: #7C5FC4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put the element that you want to center vertically inside an element that verifies `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`, itself inside a parent element that verifies `display: table; height: 100% (or whatever percentage you like); position: fixed;` :

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/g1r6esr7/1/)

HTML :

```
<div class="container">            
    <div class="centered">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="info.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">info</a></li>
            <li><a href="work.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="hku.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">hku</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
 display: table;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
}

.centered {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have reforked the jsfiddle and i think, this should be the working one.

http://jsfiddle.net/ym88m216/

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">info</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">work</a></li>
        <li><a href="hku.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">hku</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php?<?php echo "sheet=" . $kiescss; ?>">contact</a></li>
    </ul>



html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Avenir', sans-serif;
    background-color: #C9B5ED;
    color: #fff;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 7%;
    top: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 20%;
}

ul a {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

ul a:hover {
    color: #7C5FC4;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7C5FC4;
}

a:hover {
    color: #7C5FC4;
}
```